# Decomposition of a meromorphic function into a singular and holomorphic part

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, laurent-series, meromorphic-functions

Let $X$ be a normed space, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb C$ be open and $f:\Omega\to X$ be meromorphic in the sense that for all $z_0\in\Omega$, there is a $k_{z_0}\in\mathbb N_0$, $\left(a^{(z_0)}_k\right)_{k\ge-k_{z_0}}\subseteq X$ and a neighborhood $N_{z_0}\subseteq\Omega$ of $z_0$ with $$f(z)=\underbrace{\sum_{k=-k_{z_0}}^{-1}a_k^{(z_0)}(z-z_0)^k}_{=:\:m_{z_0}(z)}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k^{(z_0)}(z-z_0)^k}_{=:\:h_{z_0}(z)}\tag1$$ for all $z\in N_{z_0}\setminus\{z_0\}$. Let $P$ denote the subset of $\Omega$ for which $k_{z_0}$ cannot be chosen to be $0$.

> **EDIT**: The basic idea of this question is to consider a region $B$ of $f$, where $f$ has at most $|F|$ poles, and then to consider the Laurent expansion at the first pole, substract the principal part to obtain a function which has ony $|F|-1$ poles and continue this process until we arrive at a holomorphic function. This should somehow be similar to what is done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1557131/47771), but I don't get why we arrive at a holomorphic function **on all of $B$** at the end, since the "holomorphic parts" of each expansion are only defined on a small neighborhood of the corresponding pole ...

> Let $B\subseteq\mathbb C$ be bounded and open with $\overline B\subseteq\Omega$. Are we able to show that for $F:=B\cap P$, we can decompose $f$ on $B$ into $$f(z)=\sum_{z_0\in F}\tilde m_{z_0}(z)+h_F(z)\;\;\;\text{for all }z\in B\tag2$$ for some holomorphic $h_F:B\to X$ and $$\tilde m_{z_0}(z)=\sum_{k=-k_{z_0}}^{-1}b_k^{(z_0)}(z-z_0)^k\;\;\;\text{for all }z\in\Omega$$ for some suitable $\left(b^{(z_0)}_k\right)_{k\ge-k_{z_0}}\subseteq X$?

Since $\overline B$ is compact and $P$ is discrete, $F$ must be finite and hence the sum over $F$ in $(2)$ is finite.

We may clearly assume that $N_{z_0}$ is open for all $z_0\in F$, if that would be an issue.

My idea is the following: Consider $z_i\in P$ with $z_1\ne z_2$. We know that $P$ is discrete and hence there is a $\varepsilon>0$ with $$|z_1-z_2|\ge\varepsilon\tag3.$$ Shrinking $N_{z_i}$ if necessary, we may assume that $$N_{z_i}\subseteq B_{\varepsilon/2}(z_i)\tag4$$ and hence $$N_{z_1}\cap N_{z_2}=\emptyset.\tag5$$ Let $$N_{\{z_1,\:z_2\}}:=N_{z_1}\cup N_{z_2}$$ and $$m_{\{z_1,\:z_2\}}:=\left.\begin{cases}m_{z_1}(z)&\text{, if }z\in N_{z_1}\\m_{z_2}(z)&\text{, if }z\in N_{z_2}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }z\in N_{\{z_1,\:z_2\}}$$ (since the sum in the definition of $m_{z_i}$ is finite, $m_{z_i}$ is well-defined on all of $\Omega$). Shrinking $N_{z_i}$ if necessary, we may assume that $N_{z_1}$ and hence $N_{\{z_1,\:z_2\}}$ is open. If I'm not missing something, $$h_{\{z_1,\:z_2\}}(z):=\left.\begin{cases}h_{z_1}(z)&\text{, if }z\in N_{z_1}\\h_{z_2}(z)&\text{, if }z\in N_{z_2}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }z\in N_{\{z_1,\:z_2\}}$$ should be holomorphic.

> In the same way we should be able to construct a holomorphic function $h_F$ on $$N_F:=\bigcup_{z_0\in F}N_{z_0},$$ shrinking the $N_{z_0}$, if necessary, to ensure that this union is disjoint, with $$h_F(z)=h_{z_0}(z)\;\;\;\text{for all }z\in N_{z_0}\text{ and }z_0\in F\tag6.$$ On the other hand, by definition of $P$, the function $f$ should be holomorphic on the open set $B\setminus N_F$. Thus, the extension of $h_F$ to $B$, by setting it to $f$ on $B\setminus N_F$, should be holomorphic as well.
>
> Now we may define $$m_F(z):=m_{z_0}(z)\;\;\;\text{for }z\in N_{z_0}\text{ and }z_0\in F.$$ However, while each individual $m_{z_0}$ can clearly be extended to all of $\Omega$, we don't arrive at the desired decomposition yet. How do we need to the choose $\left(b^{(z_0)}_k\right)_{k\ge-k_{z_0}}$?

Comment: $B\subseteq\Omega$ bounded and open does *not* imply that $F=B\cap P$ is finite. You'll need that $\overline B \subseteq \Omega$ for that conclusion. I think this was mentioned in response to your previous related questions.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, fixed that.

Comment: @MartinR What I'm trying to achieve here is similar to what you wrote in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1557131/47771), but I don't get why $f-\sum_{z_0\in F}m_{z_0}$ should be holomorphic on $B$ (which should be the claim corresponding to what you wrote about $g$ being an entire function in that answer).

Comment: Holomorphy is a local property: If you subtract from $f$ all the (finitely many) principle parts from poles in $B$ then the result is a function which is holomorphic in a neighborhood of every $a \in B$, and therefore holomorphic in $B$.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, maybe this is simply a matter of notation, but I don't get that. (a) Do you really mean $f-\sum_{z_0\in F}m_{z_0}$ or do don't you actually mean $f-\sum_{z_0\in F}1_{N_{z_0}}m_{z_0}$, where $1_{N_{z_0}}$ denotes the indicator function of the set $N_{z_0}$? In the latter case, the "sum" isn't actually a sum, since all but at most one term vanish.

Comment: @MartinR (b) Moreover, we know that on $N_{z_0}\setminus\{z_0\}$ the function $f$ coincides with the function $h_{z_0}$, which is holomorphic on all of $N_{z_0}$ (i.e. it even defined on the "gap" $\{z_0\}$). So, in that sense, $h_{z_0}$ is a holomorphic extension. Are (a) and (b) what you really mean?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ is meromorphic,

$$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}-\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac1{(z-n)^2}$$ is holomorphic on $|z|<N+1$ (complex differentiable at every point, a local property). The **Cauchy integral formula** implies that it is analytic and equal to its Taylor series at $0$ for $|z|<N+1$.

It works the same way when substracting finitely many poles to any meromorphic function.

When substracting infinitely many poles it gets more complicated, for example with  $\frac{2i\pi z}{e^{2i\pi z}-1}$ then subtracting $\sum_n \frac{n}{z-n}$ won't work as it doesn't converge, instead we'll look at $\sum_n \frac{n}{z-n}+1+z/n$, generalizing this is the purpose of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to make sure that I got you right: Do you agree to my latest two comments below the question?

Comment: I am answering to those comments.

Comment: Do you mean that you *will* answer to those comments or that you already *did*? In the latter case: Could you please clarify whether you agree or disagree to (a) and (b)?

Comment: If you don't explain what you understand then I can't help. Subtracting the poles means what I did in my answer, it works *exactly* the same way for every meromorphic function.

Comment: What I mean is the following: On $N_{z_0}\setminus\{z_0\}$, we've got the decomposition $f=m_{z_0}+h_{z_0}$. Thus, on $N_{z_0}\setminus\{z_0\}$, the function $f-m_{z_0}$ coincides with the function $h_{z_0}$, which is holomorphic on $N_{z_0}$ and hence $\left.(f-m_{z_0})\right|_{N_{z_0}\setminus\{z_0\}}$ has a holomorphic extension to $N_{z_0}$.

Comment: Since $F$ is finite and the $N_{z_0}$, $z_0\in F$, can be chosen small enough to be disjoint, we can conclude that $f-\sum_{z_0\in F}1_{N_{z_0}}m_{z_0}$ (at every point, the at most one term of the sum is nonzero) is holomorphic, since it is holomorphic on $B\setminus\bigcup_{z_0\in F}\in N_{z_0}$ and on each $N_{z_0}$ it has a holomorphic extension. Is this correct?

Comment: My point is that it really confused me that some people write $f-\sum_{z_0\in F}m_{z_0}$ (i.e. without the indicator functions $1_{N_{z_0}}$), which didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Would be great if you could tell me whether you agree or disagree.

Comment: There is nothing confusing in subtracting a finite linear combination of $1/(z-z_0)^e$. It is obvious that there is no indicator function,  did I introduce any in my answer ? Why do you think anything is disjoint, in complex analysis we are dealing with analytic functions on connected open subsets of $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: To demystify where my confusion comes from: I've worked with [the definition of meromorphicity](https://tinyurl.com/y2hc3a7h) given *Spectral Theory of Infinite-Area Hyperbolic Surfaces* by David Borthwick, which also includes the poles in the domain of the function. That's why I thought it is confusing to write $f-\sum_{z_0\in F}m_{z_0}$ as it would be a function on all of $B$, but each $m_{z_0}$ is **not** even defined on $z_0\in B$. But if the poles are not in the domain of $f$, then clearly $z_0\not\in B$ and everything is fine.

Comment: I actually think that I understood how these things work and it would be great if you could tell me whether I got everything right: Assume $f:\Omega\to X$ is holomorphic and let $z_1\in\mathbb C\setminus\Omega$ be a pole of $f$ of order $k_1\in\mathbb N$. Then there is a open neighborhood $N_1$ of $z_1$ with $N_1\setminus\{z_1\}\subseteq\Omega$ and $$f(z)=\underbrace{\sum_{k=k_1}^{-1}a_k(z-z_1)^k}_{=:\:m_1(z)}+h_1(z)\;\;\;\text{for all }z\in N_{z_1}\setminus\{z_1\}$$ for some $a_{-k_1},\ldots,a_{-1}\in X$ and a holomorphic $h_1:N_1\to X$.

Comment: Now assume that $f$ has only one other isolated singularity $z_2\ne z_1$, which is a pole of $f$ as well. Since the set of isolated singularities of $f$ is discrete, we can clearly assume that $z_2\not\in N_1$ by shrinking $N_1$ if necessary. Now $f$ and $m_1$ are both holomorphic on $\Omega$ and admit the pole $z_2$ as their single isolated singularity. So, we can do the same procedure with $f_1:=f-m_1$. Do you agree?